# Using shapely unary_union() function to union polylines in ArcGIS Pro not behaving

Tags: arcpy, shapely, dissolve

I am developing an ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 toolbox (atbx) and one of the tools I'm creating is selecting a set of polylines (which are river centrelines) and merging them into a single long polyline. Research has pointed me to the shapely [unary_union()](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.unary_union.html#shapely-unary-union) function as an efficient method for merging the lines into a single polyline. I installed shapely using pip and can confirm that I have shapely '2.0.1' installed and when I import `shapely.geos` the version returned for that is '3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1'

My input data is a UK river network with some polylines selected, so data is in a file geodatabase and the Feature Class is British National Grid, I show a small example below:

[image: Input data]

I have developed the following code to do the merge:

```py
import shapely
import arcpy
xyresolution = 0.0001 # XY Resolution of Feature CLass

# Read selected polyline geometries into list
lp = list()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Rivers","SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        geom = row[0]
        lp.append(geom)

# Convert arcpy geometry into shapely geometry
ls = list()
for geom in lp:
    ls.append(shapely.set_precision(shapely.wkb.loads(bytes(geom.WKB)), xyresolution))
    
# Union lines
aLineString = shapely.unary_union(geometries=ls)

# convert line back into arcpy geometry
newpolyline = arcpy.FromWKB(aLineString.wkb)

# Write out to temporary Feature Class
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(27700) # BNG
with arcpy.EnvManager(outputCoordinateSystem=sr, addOutputsToMap=True):
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management([newpolyline], r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\fcUnionline")
```

My initial outputs all came out as MULTILINESTRING which is not what I wanted, I wanted a single linestring so I could convert back into an arcpy polyline.  More research hinted towards it being a precision issue hence me using the shapely.set_precision() function in the above code.

But even with that addition when I check the output loaded back into ArcGIS Pro, its clearly multi-part and not in sequence.

[image: Bad result]

If I go down the route of repeating the use of the [Union()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm) method of the arcpy polyline on a set of selected river centrelines, it is slow compared to the shapely.unary_union() but the end result is a single polyline, not multipart, flowing in a source to sea direction, just what I wanted.

How do I correctly use the unary_union() function?

It seems to me that it merges the lines into a single line but keeping them as separate parts. I understood the unary_union() would combine them into a single line.  For the record I have tried a range of precision values from 10 to 0.00001 and the output is exactly the same.

Comment: Had the same issue and solved with linemerge, but what's the difference with [shapely.line_merge()](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.line_merge.html#shapely.line_merge)?

Comment: geopandas.dissolve() also faces a similar issue. Is there a solution for that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the [suggestion by @user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456510/using-shapely-unary-union-function-to-union-polylines-in-arcgis-pro-not-behavi#comment745343_456510) I tweaked the code to use linemerge. So the only line that needed to change was

```py
aLineString = shapely.unary_union(geometries=ls)
```

to

```py
aLineString = shapely.ops.linemerge(ls)
```

I did have to put these import statements in to:

```py
import shapely
import shapely.wkb
import shapely.ops
```

This appears to have worked although I have yet to do any performance testing with it against repeated use of union() on an arcpy polyline. It is certainly less lines of code!

I can confirm the `linemerge` is working as expected and is blisteringly fast!  15 minutes down to 13 seconds.