# GeoPandas dissolve and explode returns original input

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

Tried to avoid posting this question, but I cannot seem to find my error.

I have a stream network shapefile that has segments that need to be dissolved to their respective segment.

Using QGIS I can use `dissolve` and then `multipart to singleparts` (no additional options are included). However, using a pythonic way, I cannot acquire the same results. The final result is the same as my input layer (see image). I know QGIS is using `gdal`, but I'd like to  avoid it since it's known to cause compatibility issues with other libraries.

```
# python = 3.10.9
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import fiona


input_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\streams.shp'

df = geopandas.read_file(input_path)
df_new = df.dissolve().explode(index_parts=True)
df_new.to_file("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.shp")
```

```
polyline = []
with fiona.open(input_path) as src:
   for feat in src:
       geom = feat.geometry
       line = LineString(geom.coordinates)
       polyline.append(line)

un = unary_union(polyline)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[un]).explode()
gdf.to_file("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.shp")
```

I've tried adding a dissolve by field, I've tried using `unary_union` from shapely instead of `geopandas.dissolve()`. I've compared the QGIS dissolve output with `geopandas.dissolve()` and `hapely.ops.unary_union` outputs. The only difference I can see is that they have a different encodings. I have found that if I use QGIS dissolve output and apply `geopandas.explode()` to it, that the wanted results are achieved. So the problem lies somewhere within dissolving the segments.

[image]

Comment: You will want to read my [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456510/using-shapely-unary-union-function-to-union-polylines-in-arcgis-pro-not-behavi). Although I'm working in ArcPro, I was facing a similar issue which I resolved.

Comment: Uhhh finally! I've got a couple of questions, but I'll post them on your Q&A. Probably should close this due to duplication.